# "Suspicious comparison of integer references" while checking for a monotonically increasing sequence

Tags: java, validation, null, reference

I have the following code which iterates on an `Integer[]` and makes sure that the the values in the array are in ascending order and that there are no neighbouring duplicates:

```
Integer previous = null;
for (Integer tb : trancheBoundaries) {
    if (previous == tb) {
        throw new IllegalThresholdConfigurationException("Two boundaries are the same");
    } else if (previous != null && previous > tb) {
        throw new IllegalThresholdConfigurationException("Previous is larger than current - tranche boundaries must be in ascending order");
    } else {
        previous = tb;
    }
}
```

I am getting a warning from Sonar warning of "suspicious comparison of integer references" on the first `if` clause.

I know why I am getting this, but in a situation like this, is it bad practice? I think it's ok because I know that I will always be comparing the same instances.

Comment: Even if it does works in your case, I think it looks too suspicions to future readers. I think you should compare with `Objects.equals` to avoid causing confusion, following "the principle of least surprise".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## `Integer[]` vs `int[]`

This may be down to a 'personal preference' thing, but using primitive wrappers in an array instead of a `Collection` seems a little odd. This is because it lets `null` values sneak into the array compared to a 'plain' `int[]`, and speaking of which...

## Boundary cases

- When this loop encounters a `null` (`previous == null`), is it really because two boundaries are the same?
- When equal numbers are encountered consecutively (`previous == tb`), is this really a case of valid ascending order?

## Miscellaneous

You can opt to remove the final `else` clause as `previous = tb` is the final 'step' in your comparison. Again, I think this is a personal preferences thing, as some may prefer to see the 'boundaries' of the `if`-blocks.

Comment: I hadn't considered the possibility of a null being in the Integer[] - looking at the code I don't see how it could happen but it pays to be sure. This is enough to make me use an int[] instead.

Comment: When equal numbers are encountered consecutively, in the context of this check, that is not a case of valid ascending order. As for your comment in the miscellaneous section, I prefer to have that in as it seems more explicit. But on the other hand the reference equals is probably less explicit!

Comment: Wouldn't `previous > tb` have to be run with `tb == null` for a `null` from the array to get into `previous`? And trying to do `> null` appears to throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @jpmc26 it can be the first element being a `null`.

Answer (score 17):

You should only use `==` if you work with elementary data types (`boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, long`).

If you use `==` on instances of classes like `Integer` you check if it is the same instance of the class not if the value is the same. You hardly ever want to check if two references refer to the same instance. That is especially true for the primitive wrappers.

**So as a rule of thump:**

- use `==` for `boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, long`
- use `equals(..)` otherwise

For little values of wrapper types `==` might work, but this totally depends on the VM implementation. [JLS 5.1.7 Boxing Conversion:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> Ideally, boxing a given primitive value p, would always yield an identical reference. In practice, this may not be feasible using existing implementation techniques. The rules above are a pragmatic compromise. The final clause above requires that certain common values always be boxed into indistinguishable objects. The implementation may cache these, lazily or eagerly. For other values, this formulation disallows any assumptions about the identity of the boxed values on the programmer's part. This would allow (but not require) sharing of some or all of these references.
>
> This ensures that in most common cases, the behavior will be the desired one, without imposing an undue performance penalty, especially on small devices. Less memory-limited implementations might, for example, cache all char and short values, as well as int and long values in the range of -32K to +32K.

Comment: I know about - but in this case the value of previous is only ever null or a value which has come from the Integer[], so I feel I can safely use the reference comparison.

Comment: new Integer(x) == new Integer(x)  might not be true, because must not be true because it depends on the VM implementation if instances are reused when representing the same value. It is likely to be true for little values because of performance reasons. But do not rely on it. I added a citation and the link to the java specification. By the way you will gain next to nothing to use '==' instead of 'equals'

Comment: I know that new Integer(x) == new Integer(x) might not be true, but I'm only ever comparing the values that come from the array. I suppose the risk is that the code that built the array could put in two different instances of Integer with the same value, thus causing the test to fail.

Comment: `new Integer(x) == new Integer(x)` will never be true, for any JLS conforming VM implementation.

Comment: yes, but I never was doing new Integer(x) == new Integer(x). I was doing myIntegerArray[x] == myIntegerArray[x].

Comment: @Rich: In this case '==' will always work for you, but why wast any thought about it, simply use 'equals(..)'

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely heed this Sonar warning.  It's not just a matter of bad style or bad practice.

[Your code will appear to work for numbers between -128 and 127,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4428779/1157100) but will break for numbers outside that range.  To check for the equality of two `Integer` values, use `.equals()`, not `==`.

Comment: In this case the value of previous is only ever null or a value which has come from the Integer[] - which I think means that I can't have the -128/127 autoboxing problem.